# How to add coupon expiry date into the followup emails?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, email

I have a woocommerce website. On that website, I am using `Followup email` plugin for sending emails to customers. From the plugin, I send a coupon code to customer by using `{coupon_code}` Email variables.

Now I want to create a new variable for coupon expiry date. Is there any way that I can hardcode in a coupon expiry date into the followup emails that customers receive?

Comment: This seems to be specific for the plugin and if so you better contact the creators of the plugin as this will be difficult to answer here.

Comment: I contacted the plugin developer but they saying there is no option right now for displaying expiry date.My question is if we can do custom code like this https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/automated-follow-up-emails-docs/custom-variables/ How we can get expiry date for custom code

Comment: To display this date, you first have to find the name of the meta field in looking the code that save it. Then you have to find how his replaced the code `{coupon_code}`